# Downloaded images upload, but camera taken images won't

Tags: android

I have an issue with a photo upload app that allows to pick an image from the device and upload it to a server. I have been following a guide on how to use the Android Upload Service library to do this. The application works for any image that was downloaded, or did not originate from the phone's camera. But whenever I choose an image from the CAMERA folder or if I take one and then try to go choose it, the image file will not show up in my uploads folder. It hits the database table, but not the image folder. When I click on the image hyperlink sent to the table column, it says "Object Not Found" I am having some real trouble understanding why it is happening for just those images particularly. Can anyone help?

Here is my MainActivity code:

```
package com.example.stins.orbotcamera;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.provider.SyncStateContract;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import net.gotev.uploadservice.MultipartUploadRequest;
import net.gotev.uploadservice.UploadNotificationConfig;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Uri file;
    private GPSTracker gps;
    private EditText imageComment;
    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    private TextView imageLat, imageLong;
    private String mLat, mLong;

    public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "http:///UploadExamples/upload.php";

    private Bitmap bitmap;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageComment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.imageComment);
        imageLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageLat);
        imageLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageLong);

        fab.setOnClickListener(this);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            fab.setEnabled(false);
            imageComment.setEnabled(false);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 0);
        }


    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                fab.setEnabled(true);
                imageComment.setEnabled(true);
            }

            else{
                coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
                final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(coordinatorLayout, "Accept all permissions to use app", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                snackbar.setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                                .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });

                snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);


                snackbar.show();
        }


        }

    }



    public void uploadImage() {
        //getting name for the image
        String name = imageComment.getText().toString().trim();

        //getting the actual path of the image
        String path = getPath(file);


        //Uploading code
        try {
            String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            //Creating a multi part request
            new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, UPLOAD_URL)
                    .addFileToUpload(path, "image") //Adding file
                    .addParameter("name", name) //Adding text parameter to the request
                    .addParameter("latitude", mLat)
                    .addParameter("longitude", mLong)
                    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                    .setMaxRetries(2)
                    .startUpload(); //Starting the upload

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        String document_id = null;
        if (cursor != null) {
            document_id = cursor.getString(0);
        }
        if (document_id != null) {
            document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        }
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        String path = null;
        if (cursor != null) {
            path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        }
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }

        return path;
    }









    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            file = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), file);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                imageComment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



        if (requestCode == 0) {
            gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                     mLat = Double.toString(latitude);
                     mLong = Double.toString(longitude);

                    imageLat.setText(mLat);
                    imageLong.setText(mLong);

                    // \n is for new line
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
                     final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                            .make(coordinatorLayout, "Current location recorded", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

                    snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                    View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                    TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                    textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_location_on_white_24dp,0,0,0);
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);


                    snackbar.show();
                } else {
                    // Can't get location.
                    // GPS or network is not enabled.
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings.

                }

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
                final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(coordinatorLayout,"Picture Cancelled", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);

                View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_cancel_white_24dp,0,0,0);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                snackbar.show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image
                coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
                final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(coordinatorLayout,"Error Taking Picture", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);

                View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_error_outline_white_24dp,0,0,0);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                snackbar.show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }





    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_send:
                if(imageView.getDrawable()==null){
                    coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
                    final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                            .make(coordinatorLayout,"Sorry, you'll need an image for that!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);

                    View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                    TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                    textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_error_outline_white_24dp,0,0,0);
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                    snackbar.show();
                }
                else {
                    uploadImage();
                }
                return true;


        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert)
                .setTitle("Exit")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close Orbot Camera?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }

                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent i;
        if(v.getId()==R.id.fab)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 0);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Check permissions

Comment: @Doomsknight Thank you for your reply! I actually checked that first because I had run into so many issues from that simple mistake. But I already supplied WRITE/READ EXTERNAL STORAGE and CAMERA permissions in Manifest. I also ask in that Main Activity as well in RequestPermissions(). No error necessarily, it just won't upload a file that was taken by the phone camera, specifically. Every other download file I choose uploads to the folder in the root directory of xampp just fine.

Comment: @Doomsknight Just found out it is ONLY the rear camera photos that won't upload to the images folder. Just took a picture with the front camera and it worked just fine.

Comment: what is the value of Uri file when it works what is the vale when it does not fork. Note the image picker may return a file uri "file://path/to/file.jpg or may return a content uri "content:....." your code only handles the case content-uri that your method getPath translates. are there cases when you get file uri-s?

Comment: okay I think I actually just figured it out to a point! I reduced the image resolution/quality from 12MP to like 3MP and it worked just fine. Does that mean the images need to be resized or compressed possibly? I know they are already either .jpg or .png so compression may reduce quality.

Comment: @k3b it is content:// uri when it works. I don't have a case to handle file:// though.